# asyncio scheduling callback at specific time

Tags: python, python-asyncio

In the following code, the callback() is not called at the repsective time(now+0.2and now+0.1) and also stopper() ,what is wrong here

```
    def callback(n,loop):
        print('Callback {} invoked at {}'.format(n,loop.time()))

    def stopper(loop):
        print("Stopper invoked at {}".format(loop.time()))
        loop.stop() 

    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        now =event_loop.time()
        print('clock time: {}'.format(time.time()))
        print('loop time: {}'.format(now))
        print('Registering callbacks')
        event_loop.call_later(now + 0.2,callback,1,event_loop)
        event_loop.call_later(now + 0.1,callback,2,event_loop)
        event_loop.call_later(now + 0.3,stopper,event_loop)
        event_loop.call_soon(callback,3,event_loop)
        print('Entering event loop')
        event_loop.run_forever()
    finally:
        print('Closing event loop')
        event_loop.close();
```

Comment: Please describe better what "not at the respective time" means. When do you expect it to be called, when is it actually being called?

Comment: callback() is not called at now+0.2 and now+0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.call_later(delay, cb, *args)` requires `delay` parameters, time delta in seconds (`float`).

But you pass `now + delay` to these calls.

Either drop `now` or replace `.call_later()` with `.call_at()`.